# How to read all records from table(> 10 million records) and serve each record as chunk response?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, playframework, akka

I try to fetch record from database using hibernate's scrollable result and with reference from [this](https://github.com/playframework/play-streaming-java) github project, i tried to send each record as chunk response.

**Controller:**

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
public Result fetchAll() {
    try {
        final Iterator<String> sourceIterator = Summary.fetchAll();
        response().setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Summary.csv");

        Source<String, ?> s =  Source.from(() -> sourceIterator);
        return ok().chunked(s.via(Flow.of(String.class).map(i -> ByteString.fromString(i+"\n")))).as(Http.MimeTypes.TEXT);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return badRequest(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
 public static Iterator<String> fetchAll() {
    StatelessSession session = ((Session) JPA.em().getDelegate()).getSessionFactory().openStatelessSession();
    org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery("select l.id from Summary l")
            .setFetchSize(Integer.MIN_VALUE).setCacheable(false).setReadOnly(true);
    ScrollableResults results = query.scroll(ScrollMode.FORWARD_ONLY);

    return new models.ScrollableResultIterator<>(results, String.class);
}
```

**Iterator:**

```
public class ScrollableResultIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
   private final ScrollableResults results;
   private final Class<T> type;

   public ScrollableResultIterator(ScrollableResults results, Class<T> type) {
      this.results = results;
      this.type = type;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean hasNext() {
      return results.next();
   }

   @Override
   public T next() {
      return type.cast(results.get(0));
   }
}
```

For test purpose, i am having 1007 records in my table, whenever i call this end point, it always return only 503 records.

Enabled AKKA log level to DEBUG and tried it again, it logs the following line for 1007 times
  `2016-07-25 19:55:38 +0530 [DEBUG] from org.hibernate.loader.Loader in application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-73 - Result row:` From the log i confirm that it fetching all, but couldn't get where the remaining one got left.

I run the same query in my workbench and i export it to a file locally and compared it with the file generated by the end point, kept LHS record generated from end point and RHS file exported from Workbench.
 First row matches, second and third didn't match. After that it got matches for alternate records until the end.

[image]

Please correct me, if am doing anything wrong and suggest me is this the correct approach for generating CSV for large db records.

For the sake of testing, i removed the CSV conversion logic in my above snippet.

Comment: hasNext calls next. I would assume that hasNext does nothing (ie. only checks) while next advances the internal cursor?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Controller code
// Prepare a chunked text stream
ExportAsChuncked eac = new ExportAsChuncked();
response().setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=results.csv");
Chunks<String> chunks = new StringChunks() {

    // Called when the stream is ready
    public void onReady(Chunks.Out<String> out) {
        try {
            eac.exportData(scrollableIterator, out);
        }catch (XOException e) {
            Logger.error(ERROR_WHILE_DOWNLOADING_RESPONSE, e);
        }
        out.close();
    }

};
// Serves this stream with 200 OK
return ok(chunks);


// Export as chunk logic
class ExportAsChuncked {
     void exportData(Iterator<String> data, Chunks.Out<String> out) {
            while(data.hasNext()) {
                  out.write(data.next());
            }
     }
}
```